# How to print an arbitrary number of split words?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to create a program in python that splits a file and then prints out however many words the user wants to see, but I keep running into problems.

This is the basic version of stuff I've been doing:

```
f = open("randomFile.txt",'r')

for idx in range(3):
    l = f.readline()
    w = l.split()
    for word in w:
        print(word)
```

But when I run it, the output looks like this, too many words:

```
Samurai
Song
By
Robert
Pilinsky
```

I've also tried using a while loop, and all sorts of for loop variants, I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Currently your code should print 3 lines worth of split words, not just 3 words

Comment: @Steve `readline()` returns an empty string if at `EOF` so there may only be a single line in the `randomFile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix could be:

```
for word in w[:3]:
    print(word)
```

So instead of the range loop:

```
f = open("randomFile.txt",'r')
l = f.readline()
w = l.split()

printcount = 3
for word in w[:printcount]:
    # prints 3 words - if .txt only has a single line
    print(word)
```

You can ask the user to define the `printcount` variable too.

```
# for python-3
printcount = input('How many words would you like to see?')

# for python-2
printcount = raw_input('How many words would you like to see?')
```

I can suggest that instead of using `l`, `f` and `w` you should use variable names `lines`, `file` and `words`. Also to read the whole file instead of line by line use `read()` instead of `readline()` - unless `.txt` contains only one line (as @AChampion mentions):

```
file = open("randomFile.txt",'r')
lines = file.read()
words = lines.split()
```

**Final Code:**

```
file = open("randomFile.txt",'r')
lines = file.read()
words = lines.split()

printcount = input('How many words would you like to see?')
for word in w[:printcount]:
    print(word)
```

Comment: When I put this into my code it would only print 2 words no matter how many words I asked for. I checked the file and all the lines and words are in it  so

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are looping 3 times, reading a line and printing all words of that line.
You can use the `idx` directly as the index into `w`.

```
with open("randomFile.txt",'r') as f:
    l = f.readline()
    w = l.split()
    for idx in range(3):
        print(w[idx])
```

Or you can do the same with `zip()` and `range()`:

```
with open("randomFile.txt",'r') as f:
    l = f.readline()
    w = l.split()
    for idx, word in zip(range(3), w):
        print(word)
```